# Android SDKTools r21 library errors

Tags: android, android-library, android-sdk-tools

I have updated today to the latest `SDKTools`, [`r21`](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) and the projects are no longer packed correctly.

I am using for instance `ActionBarSherlock` as a `library` project, and when I run the application I get the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable
```

I have reverted back to `r20` and it works again.

Did anything changed, and we should add different the `library projects`? I can't see something like this in the [Release General Notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeh, it is ADT r21 causing it.

http://tools.android.com/download/adt-21-preview#TOC-New-in-ADT-21-Preview-5
*The R classes for library projects are generated with only the IDs needed by the libraries, reducing the risk of hitting dex files limits for fields and methods.*

You need to clean up the bin folder in the library project manually.

You can check the update on Tor Norbye google+ page
https://plus.google.com/116539451797396019960/posts/KVax2483Erk

Answer (score 1):

Same problem but i have fixed it.

**What i did:**

1. Project / Clean / Build on all library projects
2. Removed the library projects and readded it on the android project
3. Android Tools / Fix Project Properties on the android project
4. Project / Clean / Build on the android project

Hope this helps and is also working for you.